# Loading PNG to TImage

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-xe

im trying to load a PNG image to a TImage using PNGImage library,

each time i do

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('c:\c.png');
```

i get :

> The file being read is not a valid "Portable Network Graphics" image
>   because it contains an invalid header. This file may be corrupted, try
>   obtaining it again

Now i guess this problem is caused by these lines(from the PngImage library):

```
{Characters for the header}
const
  PngHeader: Array[0..7] of Char = (#137, #80, #78, #71, #13, #10, #26, #10);

{Loads the image from a stream of data}
procedure TPngObject.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  Header    : Array[0..7] of Char;
  HasIDAT   : Boolean;

  {Chunks reading}
  ChunkCount : Cardinal;
  ChunkLength: Cardinal;
  ChunkName  : TChunkName;
begin
  {Initialize before start loading chunks}
  ChunkCount := 0;
  ClearChunks();
  {Reads the header}
  Stream.Read(Header[0], 8);

  {Test if the header matches}
  if Header <> PngHeader then
  begin
    RaiseError(EPNGInvalidFileHeader, EPNGInvalidFileHeaderText);
    Exit;
  end;
```

I tried changing the Char to AnsiChar but  it didn't work.

Comment: I'd love to investigate this PNG file myself. Could you please make it available?

Comment: You mean the picture im loading? here: http://google.uci.edu/images/googleicon.png

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Can you load other PNG files?

Comment: nope i cannot load any other PNG file

Comment: @yassine_hell: OK, my first thought was that the PNG was corrupted, but it seems like that isn't the case. Probably David observed the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are compiling the PNGImage unit yourself, and you have an out of date PNGImage designed for a pre-Unicode Delphi. That is the fundamental problem you have.

The PNG functionality is now built in to Delphi. The PNGImage unit is part of the standard libraries that ship with the product. Simply remove your version of the PNGImage code. Make sure you delete the .pas and .dcu files so that your errant version cannot be used.

Then include PNGImage in a uses clause in one of your units, which I guess you already do. This will result in the built in version of the unit being used.

Comment: Well i tried to remove the pngimage.pas, i can't compile anymore, and i get "Cannot resolve unit name "pngimage"..." how can i restore the built-in one

Comment: @yassine_hell: I dread to ask... Do you mean you've actually deleted the only copy of the `pngimage` you were using and are now asking how to undelete it?

Comment: For the record, the actual filename in XE2 of this unit is `Vcl.Imaging.pngimage` but with the namespaces, it's only `PNGImage`.

Comment: @Jerry That's true, but yassine uses XE which pre-dates the namespace

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing out, I was thinking XE2 naturally because that's what I use all the time.